# PHP Editor for CentOS 6.X

Tags: php, editor, centos

I have spent a full day googling around the internet for a good PHP editor for CentOS 6.x. I like Sublime Text 2 most, but this is not available either in the repositories nor as an RPM.

You guys have any good editor reference to on CentOS?

I have also tried to install Sublime Text using the way I had for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update

# Optional: remove any installed Sublime Text 2 packages:
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text*
```

But this just giving the error

> sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

I also tried `yum install sublimetext`:

> No package sublimetext available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

No luck.

Comment: Crussify me, kill me, but i love my VIM <3

Comment: @ultimateprogrammer-br hate VIM..

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question for SO, but it's worth pointing out that CentOS is just Linux, you can use any Linux text editor, including SublimeText by just downloading it and running it.

Comment: You can try gEdit or Geany or kDevelop, also :(

Comment: komodo ide/edit, eclipse

Comment: @mike Yes.. and i have also tried this and they didn't worked see the updated question.

Comment: @Mike, it's true, but i believe that he is like me, i like stuffs from official repos, i don't know why, but i like.

Comment: Seems a little nuts to me to abandon an editor you like because it's just not in a repo, but to each their own. In any case, @ravisoni, you post says nothing about Sublime not running, just not having an .rpm. It's available on their site as a binary.

Otherwise just try the countless other editors out there. Kate, gEdit, Vim, Emacs, Aptana, Sublime as we mentioned, and so on.

Comment: On [the website](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), just pick “Linux 64-bit”.

Comment: Also, you commands in the updated question aren't working because CentOS doesn't use the same package manager that Debian and Ubuntu do. Debian-based distros like Ubuntu use APT, CentOS uses yum.

Comment: @rynah post your comment as answer this worked Thanks and other too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just about any Linux, you can download the “Linux 64-bit” (or “Linux 32-bit” — the right version will probably be highlighted for you) at [the Sublime Text website](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).